# How to customize twitter/bootstrap more deeply?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just recently found twitter/bootstrap and feel it as a convenient and simple solution for people like me who do not perform well in designing and keep struggling with raw html/css codes. Especially for individual projects, bootstrap saves lots of boring work. (fixed bars, aligning center, paddings, margins etc.) However, I notice that the bootstrap only support very limited customization like colors, size, fonts etc. Does anyone know how to step by step customize the bootstrap better for specific uses. In my scenario, I am facing the following problems:

1. How to remove the embossed/projected effect of all buttons. That
   pattern seems to be over-used across the web, I prefer plain color (with a some white light)
   without these effects.
2. It seems bootstrap does not provide a solution of hover-pop-out menu, and my old script is affected by the bootstrap, not working
   anymore. Am I wrong about that? Does anyone knows that kind of
   solution. I mean the solution just like the StackExchange pop out
   menu on the top of this page.
3. Is there any way to add some self-defined new class? Like add one more button type, this kind of thing?
4. Also I am very glad to hear any good suggestions about how to leverage the advantages of bootstrap.

Also these questions pop out because I find the raw css and js codes are quite nasty, not sure  it would be a good idea to begin re-write codes without clearly knowing the direction.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap does support themes, and there are some great ones including: http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/

Comment: @JasonSperske thanks, that looks much better. But do you think it is ok to entirely use a theme created by other people?

Comment: Well for me (I have a few sites built on Bootstrap 1 and 2.3).  I just compile the .less files to get the look I'm after.  I've even built a batch file to make this easier: https://gist.github.com/jasonsperske/4560631

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basicly two ways to do this.

1. Download the .less fiels form Github, edit them to your wishes, and compile your own version of Bootsrap. It is Open Source after all. The files are well structured and documented. And though this might seem challenging if you are not familiar with less, it is actually not that hard, and there are tons of benefits to using a precompiler like less in stead of standard css. It is my method of choice! Learn more here: http://lesscss.org/
2. Create your own stylesheet, and import it **after** the bootsrap css. This way can can overwrite bootsrap styles with styles of your own, and add completly new styles.

To answer your questions individually:

1. If you follow technique 1, you could go as follows:

   - edit your version of buttons.less https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/buttons.less
   - on line 146 and following, replace the `.buttonBackground(@btnPrimaryBackground, @btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight);` by something like `background-color: @btnPrimaryBackground` and so on
   - recompile bootstrap.less, et voila!
2. How about the popover: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers You can put your own menu inside it.
3. Sure, as i described in the first part of my answer. Best would be to use option 1 for this, but should be possible both ways.
4. Again, part 1 of the answer, option 1... (I am spotting a pattern here)

Hope this helps you on the way. Enjoy bootstrap, and don't forget to check the responsive capabilities, cause that is where bootstrap excels in my opinion!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Though less should take some time to learn, I think that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: It really isn't that hard, it is very similar to css, and once you get the hang of it, you won't be able to live without!

Comment: less seems like something very similar to scss/sass. I think I get it : )